# winkey+arrow to put window to half screen not working in win10 like it did in win7

Tags: windows-10

I'm used to hitting winkey+left to move a window to the left half of the screen I'm on, and then winkey+left again will put it on the right half of the monitor I'm on if only using 1 monitor or the right half of the monitor to the left if multiple.

For some reason some of the time I hit winkey+direction, the window only moves a few pixels, and the bottom of the window moves down below the task bar.

winkey+direction always worked as expected for me in win7, ubuntu, macOS.

Hitting winkey+arrow an extra time gets around the issue, but I'd like to find a way to set winkey+left or winkey+right to always move the window to half screen on that side.

[Here is a short video showing what I'm talking about](https://youtu.be/74jN7BDauYU)

Comment: Make sure that all your snap check boxes in the multitasking section under the system tab in the settings are selected.

Comment: Works on my W10 PC, check the settings as suggested.

Comment: The only two I don't hav checked are 'automatically size it to fill available space' - I don't want this, I want half of the screen no matter what.

also I don't have "show what I can snap next to it" checked, because I don't want that either. 

@Moab can you confirm that when you hit winkey+direction that it always takes that half of the screen? For me sometimes when I hit winkey+direction the window kind of pops out and doesn't take either half of the screen.